# Draw grid in GDI+ with better performance

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I need to draw a grid with `Graphics` class (just crossed lines), and a *transparent representation* like this picture:

[image]

I don't know any other way than draw every line/rectangle. The performance is bad if the field is wide. Is there any better way to draw these things?

Here is my current code to draw the grid:

```
    private void drawGrid(Graphics pGraphic, int pGridSize)
    {
        int verticalCount = this.mPicScreen.Width / pGridSize + 1;
        int horizontalCount = this.mPicScreen.Height / pGridSize + 1;

        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Gray);

        // Vertical Lines
        for (int i = 0; i < verticalCount; i++)
        {
            pGraphic.DrawLine(p,
                new Point(i * pGridSize, 0),
                new Point(i * pGridSize, this.mPicScreen.Height));
        }

        // Horizontal Lines
        for (int i = 0; i < horizontalCount; i++)
        {
            pGraphic.DrawLine(p,
                new Point(0, i * pGridSize),
                new Point(this.mPicScreen.Width, i * pGridSize));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have already written?

Comment: @Enigmativity I just added it.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to run blazingly fast. And I'm running on a 1,920 x 1,200 screen.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I forgot turning on DoubleBuffered for the control, so it flickered too much, and I thought it was performance problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a better way: just use a brush

if you need to make a user defined grid size, you can use

```
System.Drawing.TextureBrush
```

if a random one is ok, you find in

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchBrush
```

already a grid style

Comment: Are there any tips to when trying to use a texture brush to make a grid conform with floating-point sizes?

Answer (score 0):

The control is actually flickering during the draw progress (because the control is being invalidated countinously on purpose). It's not the performance problem, but actually because the control wasn't `DoubleBuffered`.

Here is the code to enable `DoubleBuffered` on `Controls`:

```
public static void setDoubleBuffered(System.Windows.Forms.Control c)
{
    if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
        return;

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo aProp =
          typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty(
                "DoubleBuffered",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    aProp.SetValue(c, true, null);
}
```

Comment: do you really want to set hidden properties via reflection? thats the type of hacks which makes applications incompatible with next operation systems. "DoubleBuffered" is just protected - so it is possible to set it in derived classes.